# Textfield Is Hiding The Last Message of The Chat - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

**The last sent message in my chatting application is being hidden by the textfield.**

I tried to change the height of the `UICollectionView` itself so the `view` starts with the top of the `TextView`, but this is very buggy and doesn't look healthy. Especially when I have to change it every time the KeyBoard hides and shows again. It 'worked' only when the keyboard was not showing, but I still had the problem, that the user had to scroll manually down to see the last message.

```
  @objc func handleKeyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification){
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardHeight = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue.height
    let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
    let moveUp = (notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow)

    bottomConstraint?.constant = moveUp ? -keyboardHeight : 0

    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve << 16)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: options, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }){ (completed) in

        //##HERE IS THE MAIN PART##
        let isKeyBoardShowing = notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow

        if isKeyBoardShowing{

            var newSize = CGSize()
            newSize.height = (self.collectionView?.frame.size.height)! - (keyboardHeight + 48)
            newSize.width = (self.collectionView?.frame.size.width)!
            self.collectionView?.frame.size = newSize

            self.collectionView?.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1000)
        }else{
            var newSize = CGSize()
            newSize.height = (self.collectionView?.frame.size.height)! + keyboardHeight
            newSize.width = (self.collectionView?.frame.size.width)!
            self.collectionView?.frame.size = newSize
        }
    }

}
```

This picture shows the problem when the keyboard is not showing:

[image]

Same with the keyboard showing:

[image]

Comment: Use IQKeyboardManager, which manage your keyboard layout automatically. https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 0):

Check your constrains of tableview in which you are showing messages.It's bottom constrain should be from message view where you enter your message.

Remove the code of handling keyboard at your end use `IQKeyboardManagerSwift` pod for managing your keyboard and it will handle all your text fields inside your app.